# Set<Map<String, dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic> error in Flutter when writing to Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a custom user model which has a `toMap()` function:

```
Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'uid': uid,
      'email': email,
      'firstName': firstName,
    };
  }
```

I then use `toMap()` to write my user data to Firestore (by calling `set({customUser.toMap()});`):

```
  Future<void> signUp({
    required String email,
    required String firstName,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    try {
      final fbAuth.UserCredential userCredential = await firebaseAuth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      final signedInUser = userCredential.user!;

      CustomUser customUser = CustomUser(
        uid: signedInUser.uid,
        email: email,
        firstName: firstName,
      );
      await userRef.doc(signedInUser.uid).set({
        customUser.toMap()
      });
    } catch (e) {
      throw CustomError(
        code: 'Exception',
        message: e.toString(),
        plugin: 'Flutter Error / Server Error',
      );
    }
  }
```

This results in the error:

Set<Map<String, dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>

the signUp function works if I replace `customUser.toMap()` with `'uid': uid, 'email': email,` etc.

What is the issue in my custom user toMap() function that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Set<Map<String, dynamic>>`is `{ Map<String, dynamic>{} }`.

`Map<String, dynamic>` is `<String, dynamic>{}`.

In other words,

```
ex)

Set<Map<String, dynamic>> setMap ={ {'test' :'msg'} };
Map<String, dynamic> justMap = {'test':'msg'};
```

So, both are different.

This is why you are right to try as below.

(change A to B)

A

```
await userRef.doc(signedInUser.uid).set({
    customUser.toMap()
```

B

```
~~.set(
customUser.toMap()
);
```

And the toMap() you wrote above is not wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it like the following

```
Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
 final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
 data['uid'] = uid;
 data['email']= email;
 data['firstName'] = firstName;
 return data;
}
```

Define a map first and assign values to it. Then return that variable.